# How can ensure that DuckDuckGo "site:" keyword returns the same results as Googles "site:" keyword?

Tags: search, website, google-search, keyword, duckduckgo

Today, 2023-04-01, I searched using Google via these search terms:

```
site:geekhack.org "fav mouse"
```

And it returned a search result as I expected it to:

[image: Google search result]

I tried that using DuckDuckGo search but got this:

[image: DuckDuckGo search result]

Is my syntax incorrect? How can I ensure that DuckDuckGo produces same or similar results as Google?

I speculate that Google has "scraped" that website but DuckDuckGo has not. So if that is the case, then the subquestion is: What syntax do I use to tell DuckDuckGo to start "scraping" that website so that at some point in the future it will return the results?

Comment: @Rubén What part of this question "needs details or clarity"? (Asking so OP can improve their question.) Seems clear to me.

Comment: @galacticninja It might need clarity, but it is not obvious how my adding clarity now is going to "undo" the act of closing this.  From what I can tell, StackExchange sites do not provide an undo-the-close button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMLgJ.png which seems to me to be a rather conspicuously absent feature.